# How do I allow two objects being ran within threads to communicate in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm going to try to explain this the best I can, and hopefully you can understand my problem.

I'm designing a processor simulation program in Java, and right now I'm currently coding the "clock unit" which is going to control the program's execution. Basically, I have a class `ClockUnit` that changes state between 0 and 1 periodically. I need a second class `Processor` to be able to know when the clockunit class changes state, and then executes an instruction. So...

1. `ClockUnit` state = 0.
2. `Processor` does nothing.
3. `ClockUnit` change state = 1.
4. `Processor` executes instruction

At the moment I am running the `ClockUnit` class within a thread, I now need a way to run the `Processor` class and allow it to constantly check the state of the clock and when it changes to a 1 to execute an instruction. I'm not sure how to do this.

Do I need to create a second thread and run the `Processor` class from the second thread?

I hope it's clear what I need to happen. In my head its quite a simple task, I just need one thread to constantly check the state of another, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

I have posted my code below. There isn't really much complexity to it.

Main class

```
public class Main {

    private static ALU alu;
    private static ClockThread clockThread;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //two threads, both running at the same time, one thread has clock ticking, other thread gets state of ticking clock and executes on rising edge


        alu = new ALU();
        clockThread = new ClockThread("clockThread", 1);
        clockThread.start();

        while(clockThread.getClock().getState() == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("ON");
        }


    }
}
```

ClockThread class

```
import java.util.Timer;

public class ClockThread extends Thread {

    private String threadName;
    private double instructionsPerSecond;
    private Timer timer;
    private Clock clockUnit;

    public ClockThread(String name, double insPerSec)
    {
        threadName = name;
        System.out.println("Clock thread initialised");
        instructionsPerSecond = insPerSec;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        clockUnit = new Clock(instructionsPerSecond);
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(clockUnit, 0, (long) (clockUnit.timePeriod() * 1000));
    }

    public Clock getClock()
    {
        return clockUnit;
    }
}
```

Clock class

```
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Clock extends TimerTask{

    private int state = 0; //the state of the simulation, instrutions will execute on the rising edge;
    private double executionSpeed; //in Hz (instructions per second)

    private String threadName = "Clock";

    public Clock(double instructionsPerSecond)
    {
        executionSpeed = instructionsPerSecond;
        System.out.println("[Clock] Execution speed set to " + executionSpeed + "Hz. (" + timePeriod() + "s per instruction.)");
    }

    public void run()
    {
        toggleState();
        System.out.println("System State: " + state);
    }

    public void toggleState()
    {
        if(state == 1)
        {
            state = 0;
        }
        else if(state == 0)
        {
            state = 1;
        }
    }

    public double timePeriod() //takes the number of instructions per second (hz) and returns the period T (T = 1/f);
    {
        double period = 1/executionSpeed;
        return period;
    }

    public double getExecutionSpeed()
    {
        return executionSpeed;
    }

    public int getState()
    {
        return state;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question title is confusing as *threads* don't communicate; *objects* do.

Comment: You could use a producer/consumer style approach or observer pattern or some kind of monitor lock(s)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You're correct, I've adjusted the title.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you elaborate some more about what you mean by producer/consumer approach?

Comment: Lot of information has been written about use of producer-consumer both here and elsewhere, and you might wish to give it a look. Same for observer / listener pattern.

Comment: What happens when the state goes to 0?  Does the Processor finish what it is doing then stops if it finds that the state is 0?

Comment: [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html), [Producer/Consumer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html) - in fact, the [Wiki on the Producer/Consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer–consumer_problem) is probably also worth a read

Comment: @JoseMartinez The system operates like a typical processor, everytime the clock unit changes to 1, the processor executes a single instruction. Nothing happens when the clock changes to 0. The processor just needs to constantly check the state of the clock so that when the clock changes to 1 the processor can then execute the next instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a reliable clock source (the producer), you can use a BlockingQueue to send 'EdgeChange' alerts to the ALU? (the unit responsible for executing instructions).  The clock source will 'offer' the edge change event, and the ALU? will receive it (and subsequently do work).  Here is the slight changes to your code to share events across objects in different threads:

Main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    BlockingQueue<Integer> edgeAlerts = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(2);
    clockThread = new ClockThread("clockThread", 1, edgeAlerts);
    clockThread.start();
    boolean isInterrupted = false;

    while(!isInterrupted) {
        try {
            Integer edgeValue = edgeAlerts.take();
            if (edgeValue == 1) {
                System.out.println("Executing instruction");
                // Perform the instruction
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            isInterrupted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You have to pass the BlockingQueue to your ClockThread ...

```
    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> edgeAlerts;

    public ClockThread(String name, double insPerSec, BlockingQueue<Integer> edgeAlerts)
    {
        threadName = name;
        this.edgeAlerts = edgeAlerts;
        System.out.println("Clock thread initialised");
        instructionsPerSecond = insPerSec;
    }
```

And to your Clock:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Integer> edgeAlerts;

    public Clock(double instructionsPerSecond, BlockingQueue<Integer> edgeAlerts)
    {
        this.edgeAlerts = edgeAlerts;
        executionSpeed = instructionsPerSecond;
        System.out.println("[Clock] Execution speed set to " + executionSpeed + "Hz. (" + timePeriod() + "s per instruction.)");
    }
```

And your clock run becomes:

```
public void run()
    {
        toggleState();
        System.out.println("System State: " + state);
        edgeAlerts.offer(state);
    }
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: You are a wonderful human being. This works perfectly, the processor "executes" when the clock changes to state 1, exactly how I wanted it. Thank you. Just one question, the capacity of the BlockingQueue, what exactly does this mean? Edit: Also, I need to now extend this so that is works with the processor class, would it be wise to put the processor class into a separate thread? So that the clock and processor systems are both on separate threads?

Comment: Thank you.  The capacity allows the the queue to 'build up'.  in your case, if the processing is 'efficient', you will never have a build up.  But increase it if you think so.  Also, it is typical to create a consumer thread, and do the work in that thread (ie. pass the blocking queue to that thread).  Good luck with your project

Comment: An afterthought ... you may have noticed that the clock is sending an alert for all state changes.  If the processor never needs to know about a zero state, then the clock should only offer an event when state changes to 1 (but there is no real overhead in the processor receiving a zero state).

Comment: I actually wondered about this myself. If there's no difference in overhead then I think I'll just leave the functionality in for simplicity and visibility purposes. Thank you for the suggestion though.